# Paragraphs sized incorrectly when changing orientation on mobile

Tags: html, css

If my site is loaded on a mobile device in portrait orientation, when rotated to landscape, the paragraphs are way too big. If it is loaded in landscape orientation, the paragraph is the correct size as specified in the CSS.

What could be causing this issue?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="body">
        <?php include ("mainMenu.php");?>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <form id="uDF" method="post" onsubmit="submitValidation(event)">
            <p1 style="visibility: hidden" id="para">Message has been sent</p1>
            <p1 style="visibility: visible" id="emailUs">Email Us</p1>
            <input type="submit" name="uDFButton" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" id="btSub"/>
            </form>
        </div>
   </div><br><br>
   <?php include ("footer.php")?>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
 p1{
    color: #B3B3B3;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
 }
}
@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
p1{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #B3B3B3;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of your paragraph to a fixed pixel value ?

Comment: hmm no how do i set it to fixed width? max-width?

Comment: Try maybe wrapping your paragraph in a div, something like `<div style="width:200px;overflow:scroll;"><p>...</p></div>`.